# CFWheels cannot find index.cfm in views/main

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I am developing a chwheels application and until today everything was going fine. Every time I was accessing the site by www.example.com the index page was showing up and everything. Since late last night the site is giving me an error that it cannot find the file named `index.cfm` in the views/main directory.

The site is accessible though if I access it via `example.com/index.cfm?controller=main&action=index`

I do have that file and I also have a controller named `Main` under the controllers directory.

The only changes that I made before this happened was putting another file named gallery.cfm under the views/Main folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a mistake in my code with an undefined variable but wheels was not showing an error report!